# How to add message with missing links when in VBA - run-time error '1004'?

Tags: excel, vba

I need little help.
I have file with a lot of links, but sometimes one/many are not on their places and  when I use the script:

```
Sub UpdateLinks()
Dim AWB As String
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources, Type:=xlExcelLinks
End Sub
```

My idea is to see the message with witch links are broken but not stop updating the rest links.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use `On Error Resume Next` to capture your error and display a message. Don't forget to reset it to `On Error Goto 0` after you are done

Comment: Unfortunately, don't work again.